# Shell Script to find 2 digits between spaces in a filename and append a letter

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, shell-script, rename

I haven't worked much with windows shell scripts yet, but I think they'll probably the best approach for what I'm trying to accomplish

1. watch a folder for new files (otherwise I'll take the task scheduler to run the script on repeat)
2. if a new file appears, see if it contains [SPACE]IntInt[SPACE] like " 12 "
3. Append an "E" before the digits so it'll be " E12 " in the end.

I experimented a bit with findstr and ren, but finding two random integers surrounded by spaces quickly surpassed my greenhorn knowledge since I only just started to learn coding in php.

Comment: use powershell and the `-match` operator with a regex pattern. something like `-match '\s\d{2}\s'` seems like a good start. [*grin*]

Comment: and to monitor a folder for new files, you can google for PowerShell FileSystemWatcher